# How do I change the style of the legend in Flot?

Tags: flot, legend

I have just changed my version of Flot from 0.6 to 0.7, however, when I do this, the legend in my Flot graph changes style.  Previously, I had used the "LabelClass" attribute to change the style but on reading the source for 0.7 I see that "labelClass" is no longer an option and I appear to be forced to use the "table" CSS definition that is used throughout the site that I'm working on.  Because of this I can't change the site's CSS "table" definition.

Is there another good method for changing the definition of a legend or am I stuck?

Apologies in advance is this is just a newbie question

Kind Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has changed names is all, the new class is `legendLabel` for the labels and `legendColorBox` for the color box.

You can see this in [jquery.flot.js](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.js#2198).

**EDIT** in response, it seems that the question is how do you style the whole table.  Assume your flot placeholder is something like this:

```
<div id="foo" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>
```

Then you can define CSS like this:

```
#foo > div.legend > table {
  border: 2px red solid;
}
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/YkDpG/1/

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type 'tableClass' rather than "labelClass"

Comment: @ssi_bas - I edited my answer to show some details on how to style the legend as a whole

Comment: thanks for the info, I tried it with FF and it works (though I have some other issues I need to deal with), however when I try it with IE6 (which is the target browser, unfortunately) there is no change to the legend style.  Any ideas (apart from dumping IE6, that is)?

Comment: Oh, yes - you can't use the same CSS selectors in IE6, sadly...  just get rid of both `>` in the CSS selector and just have single spaces instead (i.e. `#foo div.legend table`)

Comment: I have used like what you have mentioned in your answer, it works fine. but, even after i move the legend out of the plot are to make the graph fully visible, i get the `opacity` alone set and cannot be over ridden. is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to style the legend is to use the jQuery `.css()` (http://api.jquery.com/css/) method after the chart has been plotted.

For example:

```
$.plot($("#chartFoo"), pieChartData, options);
$("#chartFoo div.legend table").css("border", "1px solid #888888");
$("#chartFoo div.legend table").css("background", "#ffffee");
```

or:

```
$.plot($("#chartFoo"), pieChartData, options);
$("#chartFoo div.legend table").css({ border: "1px solid #888888", background: "#ffffee" });
```